# vector multiplication in pytorch

Tags: vector, pytorch, torch

In pytorch. I want to multiply each vector of Matrix A by each vector of Matrix B:

```
A      = M x N
B      = L x N
result = (M x L) x N
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = A[:, None, :] * B[None, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it is working:

```
torch.einsum('bj,aj->baj', input_unfolded, self.weights)
```

You can design any multiplication pattern using this approach.